# Tizen native web view: How to store and restore cookies in a native web view?

Tags: webview, tizen, tizen-native-app

I am trying to develop a native web view app and it is working good.
But every time I close and restart the app all login/cookie information is lost.
How can I store and restore cookies in a native web view?

What is very weird: The HTML5 Web Storage (local db) gets restored, but the cookies aren't available anymore!?

Do you have any information for me?

Here is the basic code that I am using (from a Samsung example):

```
#include "webviewexample.h"

// Header files needed for  EWK Webkit
#include <Ecore.h>
#include <Ecore_Evas.h>
#include <Ecore_Getopt.h>
#include <Eet.h>
#include <Eina.h>
#include <Elementary.h>
#include <Evas.h>
#include <EWebKit.h>
#include <app.h>

typedef struct appdata {
    Evas_Object *win;
    Evas_Object *conform;
    Evas_Object *label;
    Evas_Object *entry;
    Evas_Object *web_view;
    Evas_Object *back_button;
    Evas_Object *forward_button;
} appdata_s;

static void
win_back_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
{
    appdata_s *ad = data;
    /* Let window go to hide state. */
    elm_win_iconified_set(ad->win, EINA_TRUE);
}

static void
btn_go_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
{
    appdata_s* ad = data;
    ewk_view_url_set(ad->web_view, elm_object_text_get(ad->entry) );
}

static void
btn_prev_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
{
    appdata_s* ad = data;
    if( ewk_view_back_possible( ad->web_view ) == EINA_TRUE )
        ewk_view_back( ad->web_view );
}

static void
btn_next_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
{
    appdata_s* ad = data;
    if( ewk_view_forward_possible( ad->web_view ) == EINA_TRUE )
        ewk_view_forward( ad->web_view );
}

static void
my_table_pack(Evas_Object *table, Evas_Object *child, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
   evas_object_size_hint_align_set(child, EVAS_HINT_FILL, EVAS_HINT_FILL);
   evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(child, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
   elm_table_pack(table, child, x, y, w, h);
   evas_object_show(child);
}

static void
create_base_gui(appdata_s *ad)
{
    /* set up policy to exit when last window is closed */
    elm_policy_set(ELM_POLICY_QUIT, ELM_POLICY_QUIT_LAST_WINDOW_CLOSED);
    /* Window */
    ad->win = elm_win_util_standard_add(PACKAGE, PACKAGE);
    elm_win_autodel_set(ad->win, EINA_TRUE);

    int rots[4] = { 0, 90, 180, 270 };
    elm_win_wm_rotation_available_rotations_set(ad->win, (const int *)(&rots), 4);

    eext_object_event_callback_add(ad->win, EEXT_CALLBACK_BACK, win_back_cb, ad);

    {
        /* Box to put the table in so we can bottom-align the table
         * window will stretch all resize object content to win size */
        Evas_Object *box = elm_box_add(ad->win);
        evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(box, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
        elm_win_resize_object_add(ad->win, box);
        evas_object_show(box);

        /* Table */
        Evas_Object *table = elm_table_add(ad->win);
        /* Make table homogenous - every cell will be the same size */
        elm_table_homogeneous_set(table, EINA_TRUE);
        /* Set padding of 10 pixels multiplied by scale factor of UI */
        elm_table_padding_set(table, 5 * elm_config_scale_get(), 10 * elm_config_scale_get());
        /* Let the table child allocation area expand within in the box */
        evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(table, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
        /* Set table to fiill width but align to bottom of box */
        evas_object_size_hint_align_set(table, EVAS_HINT_FILL, EVAS_HINT_FILL);
        elm_box_pack_end(box, table);
        evas_object_show(table);

        {
            /* Entry */
            ad->entry = elm_entry_add(ad->win);
            elm_entry_scrollable_set(ad->entry, EINA_TRUE);
            eext_entry_selection_back_event_allow_set(ad->entry, EINA_TRUE);
            elm_object_text_set(ad->entry, "http://www.tizen.org");
            my_table_pack(table, ad->entry, 0, 0, 3, 1);

            /* Button-1 */
            Evas_Object *btn = elm_button_add(ad->win);
            elm_object_text_set(btn, "Prev");
            evas_object_smart_callback_add(btn, "clicked", btn_prev_cb, ad);
            my_table_pack(table, btn, 0, 1, 1, 1);

            /* Button-2 */
            btn = elm_button_add(ad->win);
            elm_object_text_set(btn, "Go");
            evas_object_smart_callback_add(btn, "clicked", btn_go_cb, ad);
            my_table_pack(table, btn, 1, 1, 1, 1);

            /* Button-3 */
            btn = elm_button_add(ad->win);
            elm_object_text_set(btn, "Next");
            evas_object_smart_callback_add(btn, "clicked", btn_next_cb, ad);
            my_table_pack(table, btn, 2, 1, 1, 1);

            /* WebView */
            Evas *evas = evas_object_evas_get(ad->win);
            ad->web_view = ewk_view_add(evas);
            ewk_view_url_set(ad->web_view, elm_object_text_get(ad->entry) );
            my_table_pack(table, ad->web_view, 0, 2, 3, 8);

        }
    }

    /* Show window after base gui is set up */
    evas_object_show(ad->win);
}

static bool
app_create(void *data)
{
    /* Hook to take necessary actions before main event loop starts
        Initialize UI resources and application's data
        If this function returns true, the main loop of application starts
        If this function returns false, the application is terminated */
    appdata_s *ad = data;

    create_base_gui(ad);

    return true;
}

static void
app_control(app_control_h app_control, void *data)
{
    /* Handle the launch request. */
}

static void
app_pause(void *data)
{
    /* Take necessary actions when application becomes invisible. */
}

static void
app_resume(void *data)
{
    /* Take necessary actions when application becomes visible. */
}

static void
app_terminate(void *data)
{
    /* Release all resources. */
    ewk_shutdown();
}

static void
ui_app_lang_changed(app_event_info_h event_info, void *user_data)
{
    /*APP_EVENT_LANGUAGE_CHANGED*/
    char *locale = NULL;
    system_settings_get_value_string(SYSTEM_SETTINGS_KEY_LOCALE_LANGUAGE, &locale);
    elm_language_set(locale);
    free(locale);
    return;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    appdata_s ad = {0,};
    memset(&ad, 0x00, sizeof(appdata_s));
    int ret = 0;

    ui_app_lifecycle_callback_s event_callback = {0,};
    memset(&event_callback, 0x00, sizeof(ui_app_lifecycle_callback_s));
    app_event_handler_h handlers[5] = {NULL, };


    event_callback.create = app_create;
    event_callback.terminate = app_terminate;
    event_callback.pause = app_pause;
    event_callback.resume = app_resume;
    event_callback.app_control = app_control;

    ui_app_add_event_handler(&handlers[APP_EVENT_LANGUAGE_CHANGED], APP_EVENT_LANGUAGE_CHANGED, ui_app_lang_changed, &ad);

    ret = ui_app_main(argc, argv, &event_callback, &ad);
    if (ret != APP_ERROR_NONE) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "app_main() is failed. err = %d", ret);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

The manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns="http://tizen.org/ns/packages" api-version="2.4" package="org.example.webviewexample" version="1.0.0">
    <profile name="mobile"/>
    <ui-application appid="org.example.webviewexample" exec="webviewexample" launch_mode="single" multiple="false" nodisplay="false" taskmanage="true" type="capp">
        <label>webviewexample</label>
        <icon>webviewexample.png</icon>
    </ui-application>
    <privileges>
        <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/network.get</privilege>
        <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/appmanager.launch</privilege>
        <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/location</privilege>
        <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/internet</privilege>
        <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/notification</privilege>
        <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/display</privilege>
        <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/camera</privilege>
        <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/externalstorage</privilege>
        <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/content.write</privilege>
    </privileges>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answer, but I have not been able to solve it.
I have now solved it via a workaround:
1. via Javascript I save the cookies in the LocalStorage.
2. when starting the app I read the data from the LocalStorage and create the cookies again.

That's how it works for me.

Comment: Hello, can you elaborate on the code please? I am in the same situation now and I cannot get it working with the native API's

Answer (score 0):

You may Checkout the [EWebKit: WebView API References](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__WEBVIEW.html) for API functions related to Cookies.

relevant terms/functions on API references:

[Ewk Cookie Manager](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__WEBVIEW.html#ga55445760efc0297c03f50683f2514e5c),

[Ewk_Cookie_Persistent_Storage](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__WEBVIEW.html#ga5b342d34de4ae801cce0559da2589a7f),

[ewk_cookie_manager_persistent_storage_set ()](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__WEBVIEW.html#ga6983aa25d7ef20bb795d8abb5f07592f),

[Ewk_Cookie_Accept_Policy](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__WEBVIEW.html#ga0a497ed209ddeee0e7c033e666646f91)